# Find Eigenvectors of a homomorphism over polynomial vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathbb{R}[x]$ be the real-valued vector space of polynomials with real-valued coefficients and $F: \mathbb{R}[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}[x]$ be a homomorphism defined as
$$
F(f(x)):=(x^2-1)f''(x)+2xf'(x),
$$
where $f'$ is the derivative of $f$. Prove that for all $n\geq 0$, there exists exactly one polynomial $p_n(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ of degree $n$ with leading coefficient 1, such that $p_n(x)$ is an Eigenvector of F.

---

I computed $F(x^i)=\ldots=(i^2+i)x^i + (i-i^2)x^{i-2}$, resulting in the representing matrix for $F$, but I don't know how I could prove the statement:
$$M:=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0&\\
0 & 2 & 0 & -6 & 0&\\
0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & -12& \ldots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 12 & 0&\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 20&\\
&&\ldots
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: A matrix of infinite order to calculate eigenvalues/eigenvectors? It may take a while...

Comment: Try first with the low degree cases.

Comment: Ok, so then calculating the matrix is useless? What else should I do?

Comment: Not useless, it's very good. You can also calculate directly the eigenvectors. Do you see it in cases when degree is $0,1,2$?

Comment: For $n=0$, it's just a matrix with one entry, namely 0, so Eigenvector should be 1, Eigenvalue 0. For $n=1$, $M:=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$, is it Eigenvector $(0, 1)^t$, Eigenvalue 2? I'm not sure if I'm reading it off of the matrix correctly.

Comment: Yes, good, the eigen-"vector" itself is now *coordinated* as $(0,1)^T$, indeed, in the standard basis of polynomials. That is, it is the polynomial $x$. It has indeed eigenvalue $2$, you can easily check it. Can you find a quadratic polynomial $f$ which becomes $6f$ by applying $F$? (The eigenvalue will be $6$ for any quadratic eigenvector.)

Answer (score 1):

Assume that a polynomial $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$ is eigenvector of $F$, then
$Ff=\lambda f$ and, comparing the coefficients of $x^n$, we get
$$ n(n-1)+2n=\lambda$$
so that $\lambda=n^2+n=n(n+1)$, which is *different* for all $n$'s.

Now, for uniqueness, assume that $f$ and $g$ are different normed polynomials of degree $n$, and that both are eigenvectors of $F$. Then $f-g$ is also eigenvector with the *same* eigenvalue $n(n+1)$, but $d:=\deg(f-g)<n$, so if it has eigenvalue, that must be $d(d+1)$ by the previous reasoning.

For the existence, if we restrict the space to polynomials of degree $\le N$ for some $N$, then this subspace is invariant under $F$, and $F$ has characteristic polynomial $\lambda(\lambda-1\cdot 2)(\lambda-2\cdot 3)(\lambda-3\cdot 4)\dots(\lambda-N\cdot (N+1))$, which has $N+1$ different roots, so these are indeed eigenvalues, so there belong some eigenvectors to each.